# stat() doesn't work on parent directory

Tags: c, directory, parent, stat

I'm trying to code the `ls` command in C, but `stat()` refuse to open any other directory.

```
 ~/Desktop/ls$ cat bug.c 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  DIR       *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  struct stat   file;

  d = opendir(av[1]);
  if (d)
    {
      while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
          printf("%s ->", dir->d_name);
          if (lstat(dir->d_name, &file) < 0)
          printf(" can't read file %s!", dir->d_name);
          printf("\n");
        }
    }
  closedir(d);
  return (0);
}
```

When running `./a.out` . or any subfolder, it works correctly.
But if I write `./a.out ..` , it fails to open files...

```
~/Desktop/ls$ ./a.out ..
.. ->
fkdkfdjkfdkfjdfkdfjkdfjkdjkfdkjf -> can't read file fkdkfdjkfdkfjdfkdfjkdfjkdjkfdkjf!
ss -> can't read file ss!
ls -> can't read file ls!
. ->
tg -> can't read file tg!
```

`./a.out /home/login/Desktop` doesn't work either, but `./a.out /home/login/Desktop/ls/` display correctly the content of the current folder.

It looks like `a.out` can't open parents dir, but `ls -l` gives :

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 hellomynameis hellomynameis 13360 nov.  25 09:56 a.out
```

Am I doing it the wrong way ?

Thanks !

Comment: I cannot see 'fkdkfdjkfdkfjdfkdfjkdfjkdjkfdkjf' in your 'ls' output.  stat() cannot report on files it cannot find.  Did you mean to run stat on '../fkdkfdjkfdkfjdfkdfjkdfjkdjkfdkjf' ?

Comment: regarding `stat()`,  1) it must be passed the complete (can be relative or absolute) path,  even the current directory should be referenced as `./`  2) a directory/file must have the appropriate permission for the currently executing program to read the directory/file.  This includes any/all directories in the 'path' parameter

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  always enable all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: When accessing any argv[] entry beyond argv[0] always check the value of argc to assure the command line parameter actually exists.  Otherwise could be access a NULL pointer or some random value in memory if the use did not actually enter the necessary command line parameter(s)

Comment: the posted code (probably) does not want to try opening the directory entries `.` and `..`, so should check the directory name to assure it is neither of these values.  (be sure to use something like strcmp() so a file or directory name that starts with `.` is not skipped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `lstat` call is wrong. When you get a name from the opened directory, it is a relative name, so you need to convert it to a correct path to let `lstat` locate the file:

```
char path[...];
sprintf(path,"%s/%s",av[1],dir->d_name);
lstat(path,...);
```

Comment: May need a '/' delimiter in there?

Comment: Sure! You need to construct something like `../filename`

Answer (score 1):

The program a.out may has not permission to read all the files in that folder. Try to run a.out with root permission.

And, if you want to check the error, please print the **errno** to get the detail of **error** when the **lstat** function does not execute success.